# Jquery onclick popup tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

I need the javascript code for tooltip to appear onclick for 10 seconds

Mostly Without using html code, or any plugins

```
$('a.pet_type_link').click(function() {
 //I need tooltip to appear for 10seconds
});
```

I am using coffescript and haml code.

Comment: Are these links navigates to other pages? Do you have created the tooltip html?

Comment: I don't understand "tooltip html"

Comment: i mean do you have your customized tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

```
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tooltip").hide('fast');//change these options 
    }, 500);
```

Are you looking for [Tooltip timeout](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyhY/695/) ??

Change the time delay in timeout function  as per your requirement.

Comment: Onclick tooltip, and it should only last for 10senconds

Comment: Its not onclick, its mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Check this example it is sounds similar to your query

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-animation